# Regex for matching template name

Tags: regex, match

This should be pretty easy but for some reason it's not. I'm trying to match names of template file, which can contain `.-_` characters and always end with `.html`. Valid examples :

```
my-tem-plate.html
my.tem-plate.html
my_tem.plate.html
```

With my current regex :

```
/(\w|\.|\-|\_)+.html/
```

tested on a path with filename :

```
'/src/blabla/select-tab.tpl.html'
```

I'm getting two matches in array instead of just one.

```
["select-tab.tpl.html", "l"]
```

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: try this `^[.\w-]+\.html$` , which lang are you running?

Comment: `OR` statements can be done simpler and more readable with `[\w\.\-\_]+`

Comment: *Can* contain or *must* contain?

Comment: I'm running this in javascript

Comment: CAN contain. Some names are as simple as main.html

Comment: @AvinashRaj without the word boundary it gives promising results.

Comment: What do you mean by without the boundary? Is my regex works for you?

Comment: I mean the ^ character. Sorry it's the beginning of the string, not word boundary. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is already (kinda) working: when you use `str.match(/regex/)` in javascript it returns an array composed by

- the whole match as the first item
- the captured values as the following items

In `/(\w|\.|\-|\_)+.html/` you are using a capturing group `(...)`, the second item in your result is that captured value (here, the last letter before `.html`).

You could just discard everything except the first item in your resulting array, but since you don't need to capture this value in the first place you can just use instead:

```
/[\w.-]+\.html/
```

On top of that, **a few comments**:

- to indicate any character can be used in a set of characters use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): `[...]` (please note the metacharacter are different there)
- `\w` is a shortcut for `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`, no need to add the underscore by hand